# URL rewrite is accepting any prefix (subdomain)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the users typing entering site by typing `http: // mysite . com` or just mysite . com (without www) to `www . mysite . com`. Blow URL rewrite condition and rule I am currently using in .htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is functioning properly but I noticed another problem recently. The site is accepting request what ever subdomain is typed such as `abc.mysite.com` or `xyz.mysite.com` or anythingyoutype.mysite.com and prefixing www (www.antyingyoutype.mysite.com) . This is not something we want. I am not sure if this issue was there since the time I uncommitted the rewrite rule or there is something else has causing this issue. Please help me fix.

My site is running in Drupal7 + LAMP + Ubuntu environment

Comment: Prefixing as in it's turning `abc.mysite.com` into `www.abc.mysite.com`? Or it becomes `www.mysite.com`?

Comment: becomes www.anythingyoutype.mysite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rules like this to add `www` to main site only:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

**Optionally if you want to block all other wildcard domains then use this rule:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: any help on how to use these rules in IIS config files for .net env

Comment: Sorry I don't know IIS